# Would "to bomb" mean "to fart" in English?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

My native language is Vietnamese. And In Vietnamese, when you say

**She bombs a lot when she is pregnant** (saying in Vietnamese ways).

It literally means "**She farts a lot...**"

*Would "**to bomb**" mean "**to fart**" in English?*

Comment: Did you look up "to bomb" in a dictionary?  What did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To bomb* isn't normally used that way, but there is the expression

> **drop a bomb**
>   3. (Britain, slang, euphemistic) To fart.
>   *Let's say you're at school and you accidentally **drop a bomb** in class. Try coughing or dropping a book to cover up the sound.* - 2004, Bart King, Chris Sabatino, The Big Book of Boy Stuff, page 129

It's not normally used in the plural, though.